# DOM manipulations take effect only after running the entire PyScript code

Tags: javascript, html, dom, progress, pyscript

Javascript-style DOM manipulations of the HTML document seem to take effect only after running the entire PyScript code. Example:

```
<div id="progress"></div>

<py-script>
   # Some code
   js.document.getElementById("progress").textContent = "Continuing with the next computations..."
   # Some more code
</py-script>
```

This may not be problematic in many cases, but my PyScript code takes several minutes to finish and I am using DOM manipulation as a way to inform users of the progress.

Is there any way to update the DOM immediately in PyScript?

Answer (score 0):

More information is required to determine how to handle your situation. But here's an example of running async python code in py-script if it helps.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p id="progress">Progress bar placeholder</p>

  <py-script>
      import asyncio
    
      async def updateText(i):
          js.document.getElementById("progress").textContent = f"Running... {i}"
          print(i)
          await asyncio.sleep(1)

      async def main():
          for i in range(10):
              await updateText(i)

      asyncio.ensure_future(main())
  </py-script>

</body>
```